# Thoughts about event frequencies and "often enough"

Tags: word-choice, usage, translation

I'm having trouble expressing the concept of "not often enough".  The most basic way to say "often" is `よく`, but I think there's a problem in putting qualifiers on this word.  For instance, expressing "more often" with `もっとよく` would be unnatural and/or wrong.

Here are two examples from [The Jim Breen dictionary](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1Q%C9%D1%C8%CB_1_) for the word [頻]{ひん}[繁]{ぱん} that answer part of my question. This expresses a "more often" concept:

> メアリーは、もっと頻繁に母親を手伝うと約束した。
>   Mary promised her mother that she would help her more often.

This is almost to the point of expressing *a degree of frequency*, but I feel like it comes up short for what I'm grasping for:

> できるだけ頻繁に辞書を引きなさい。
>   Refer to the dictionary as often as possible.

How would you say "not often enough"?  I'm tempted to try something like `頻繁さが足りない`, but that has no Google results so it's probably wrong.  Would it be acceptable to use `頻度` instead?  Let's say I wanted to say "I don't get updates often enough" or something like that.  What are the best ways to express this type of thought?

Comment: btw, I don't know why the interface won't let me insert a link (see dictionary link), but it just won't work for some reason.

Comment: Probably it would help if you ask with context rather than just for the phrase "not often enough". It could be that the best way to say it is to use a different structure.

Comment: @sawa For context, I would just change that statement about Mary to "Mary didn't help out enough".  Even though it seems really simple, I'm at a loss for how to form that, and I'm not sure if it would even use the same words and general structure here.

Comment: That's the point of my comment. By the way, your English sentence "Mary didn't help out enough" doesn't include "often". Accordingly, the Japanese sentence will not either. Is that what you want? You need to specifically provide a context where the frequency matters. Otherwise, in Japanese the frequency will probably not be expressed.

Comment: @sawa I'm sorry, I should have said "Mary didn't help out often enough", that was just careless.

Comment: I think your mistake suggests an important point, and that is what I was trying to tell you in the previous comment. Perhaps, in that case, the frequency does not matter, so you subconsciously wrote an English sentence without using the word "often". The same thing with Japanese. Unless you think of a context where the frequency really matters rather than just "a general amount", the most natural way to say it in Japanese is to not particularly mention the frequency but just say "(not) enough".

Comment: We'd just say あまり～～しない, no?

Comment: I don't forget the possibilities that the verb-て くれる construction allows. どうして(あまり)言ってくれないの？ has a nice, whiny/righteous feel to it.